# how to insert, select query data into other target database using different context transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, transactions, sql-insert

I want to insert some records that has been fetched from select query using one context transaction,

```
var data = Database.Select(transactionObject, $@"Select * from " + table);
```

and now i want to insert this data into another transaction of different database having different context,

```
foreach(var record in data){
    IDeferredCommand InsertDataToTarget = Database.ExecuteDeferred(RmTrxn, $@"insert into table tablename values("+ record +");");
     InsertDataToTarget.Execute(); }
```

here, is there any way i can insert that "record" object directly as column values for table?